# Is there a Python library to group values of Col B based on Col A and display all values of a group in a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-munging

I want the following data to be converted like the below expected output.
Values of 2nd column must be grouped and displayed in a single row based on values in 1st column.
I can use my own logic in Python to do this, but wanted to know if Pandas or any other library in Python provides such functionality to make it easier.

Input:

```
1   A
1   B
1   B
2   D
3   A
1   C
4   D
2   A
1   A
3   B
4   A
2   D
2   C
4   C
4   B
4   A
3   A
```

The expected result:

```
1   A   B   B   C   A
2   D   A   D   C   
3   A   B   A       
4   D   A   C   B   A
```

Comment: Another question similar to this has been posted, grouping based on time interval.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55827409/1362817?sem=2
Could anyone please give some hints for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use assuming `0` is the first column and `1` is the second. if first column is index replace `0` with `df.index`

```
m=df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
print(pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index=m.index).rename_axis(None).fillna(''))
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3  4
1  A  B  B  C  A
2  D  A  D  C   
3  A  B  A      
4  D  A  C  B  A
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes `pandas` can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe (or import it)
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4], "letter" : ["A", "A", "B", "D", "A", "C", "B", "B"]})

print(df)
```

Result:

```py
    id  letter
0   1   A
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   2   D
4   2   A
5   3   C
6   1   B
7   4   B
```

Then:

```py
df.groupby("id").sum()
print(df)
```

Result:

```py
id  letter
1   AABB
2   DA
3   C
4   B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('id').sum()['letter'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

id
1    A B B C A
2      D A D C
3        A B A
4    D A C B A
```